# What is やっちゃるけんな?

Tags: meaning, slang, colloquial-language

This looks like やる in a colloquial form. Can someone clear up what this says?

Answer (score 3):

やっちゃるけんな(in the Kyushu dialect)＝やってやるからな＝やってやるぞ

Comment: けん isn't the same thing as いけません?

Comment: Nope, you must be confusing けん with いけん. They often say ～だけん（ね/な）/～するけん（ね/な）to mean ～だから（ね/な）/～するから（ね/な）etc.